# Beyond Compare 4 failing as git difftool on OSX when already running

Tags: git, macos, beyondcompare, git-difftool, beyondcompare4

I've recently switched to using Beyond Compare as my git difftool/mergetool on OSX. It works fine when Beyond Compare is **not** already running - `git difftool A B` works as expected with A appearing in the left pane and B appearing in the right pane.

However, if a Beyond Compare session is already open, the same command results in the left page displaying `/Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/Info.plist` and the right pane being blank. This is pretty annoying as I have to quit BC entirely in order for the next difftool session to work correctly and I'm also using BC as an SFTP client to sync files with a remote server.

I'm using Beyond Compare 4.1.2, git 2.6.3, OSX 10.11

The relevant section of my ~/.gitconfig (taken from [Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?11677-Using-BC4-OSX-with-Version-Control-Systems)):

```
[diff]
    tool = bcomp
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bcomp"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = "/usr/local/bin/bcomp" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[merge]
    tool = bcomp
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
[mergetool "bcomp"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = "/usr/local/bin/bcomp" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
```

where `/usr/local/bin/bcomp -> /Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/MacOS/bcomp`

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try the updated instructions from Scooter Software's knowledge base.

Launch Beyond Compare, go to the Beyond Compare menu and run Install Command Line Tools.

**Diff**

```
git config --global diff.tool bc3
```

To launch a diff using Beyond Compare, use the command:  git difftool file.ext

**Merge** (Pro only)

```
git config --global merge.tool bc3
git config --global mergetool.bc3 trustExitCode true
```

To launch a 3-way merge using Beyond Compare, use the command:  git mergetool file.ext

I tested the above instructions using BC 4.1.3, OS X 10.11, and Git 2.5.4 and launching two "git difftool file.ext" from separate terminals opened in Beyond Compare without issue.

Reference: [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems under OS X](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx#git)

Answer (score 0):

I had to additionally open BC4 and go to `Session Settings > Handling` and

1. Turn ON `Follow Symbolic Links` checkbox
2. At bottom left, the dropdown with `Use for this view only` set to `Also update session defaults`

from this scooter support thread: https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/forum/beyond-compare-4-discussion/mac/11149-git-difftool-dir-diff-not-working-with-bc4-on-os-x